# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, api

[image: the javascript file picture]

this the file, and it's saying

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at app.js:25
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let long;
    let lat;
    let temperatureTimeZone = document.querySelector("temperature-timezone");
    let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector("temperature-degree");
    let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector("temperature-description");

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            long = position.coords.longitude;
            lat = position.coords.longitude;

            const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
            const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/1299787a9e937056e2ee6cb21ebfc2d4/${lat},${long}`;

            fetch(api)
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    const { temperature, summary, precipType, icon } = data.currently;

                    // set Dom Elements from APi
                    temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature;
                });
        });
    } else {
        h1.textcontent = "Hey reload site and allow geolocation";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "temperature-degree"? If it's an id, then you must do "#temperature-degree". If it's a class, then you must do ".temperature-degree". If it's a tag, then you don't have any symbols, but "temperature-degree" shouldn't be a tag. If you're still confused, look at the documentation for it: [developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: <h2 class="temperature-degree">34</h2> is the temperature-degree

Comment: Happy to help you!